# Metric where a Ellipse is a Sphere

Tags: metric-spaces

A need to show, in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, a metric where a Ellipse is a Sphere and I got no idea on how to proceed. Thanks!

Comment: try: $ d((x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2)) = \sqrt{\frac{(x_1-x_2)^2}{a^2} + \frac{(y_1-y_2)^2}{b^2}} $ ?

Comment: Thats nice, added up with the hint of N. S. it may solve my problem. I've made a comment in his answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** A sphere in your metric is
$$d((x,y),(x_0,y_0))=R$$

You need this to become the equation of an ellipse. What is the equation of an ellipse?

Comment: Ok, if I make just like Loutcho did in the comments session: define $d((x,y),(x_{1},y_{1})) = \sqrt{\frac{(x-x_{1})^{2}}{a^2} + \frac{(y-y_{1})^{2}}{b^2}}$, then $\frac{(x-x_{1})^{2}}{a^2} + \frac{(y-y_{1})^{2}}{b^2} = R^{2}$, therefore, it is an ellipse equation. Then, any point in the ellipse will lie in the Sphere of radius $R$. Is it correct? Thanks!

Comment: @GuilhermeNetto Yes. The point I was trying to make is that you could have easily figure the answer by yourself: You need $d((x,y),(x_1,y_1))=R$ to become $$\frac{(x-x_{1})^{2}}{a^2} + \frac{(y-y_{1})^{2}}{b^2} = R^{2}$$ THis equation is $$\sqrt{\frac{(x-x_{1})^{2}}{a^2} + \frac{(y-y_{1})^{2}}{b^2} }= R$$ and you need $$d((x,y),(x_1,y_1))=R$$ So what should $d((x,y),(x_1,y_1))$ be?